# Apache RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration, config, httpd.conf

I am all new to Apache mod_rewrite, RewriteRule and regexp. I'm trying to do this:

All requests to http://x.y.com/path/* shall go to http://x.z.com/path/*

One (potential) problem here is that both x.y.com and x.z.com are ServerAlias(es) on the same Apache instance.

Background: We are using eZ Publish and need to redirect certain URLs from a mobile design to a "full" browser based design. We do not have responsive design so we are bound to use two different designs that matches host.

We do not do any redirects based on browser because we want the ability for the users to view both sites.

Comment: Anyone that can help?